# Animação em Android, circulo emitindo ondas

Tags: android, animação

Preciso fazer um efeito parecido com o do `ZenUI` em `call`, que a foto com circulo emite ondas (zoon dele por baixo) como pode se ver no vídeo http://youtu.be/niWK2U71t28?t=1m38s

Será que muita ajuda, porque eu nem sei por onde começar a pesquisa!

Estou utilizando Android Studio com a imagem já com *border* e em *circle*:

```
<br.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivFotoEncontre"
        android:src="@drawable/photo_defalt"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar várias `ImageView's`, cada uma com um raio diferente da outra e com tonalidades `alpha` diferentes também. Dessa forma, ao receber uma ligação, você pode fazer uma animação que brinque com a visibilidade criando um efeito de "onda".

Comment: Só complementando, que também pode ser usado FrameLayout para sobrepor as ImageViews.

Comment: A ideia não é ruim! Eu também faria desta forma se fosse o caso, centralizando as ImageView's alpha's na principal.